# How to perform casting with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, casting

My classes structure is like:

```
class MethodHelper : public QObject, public IMethodHelper {
public:
    // Stuff
};
```

Now, I get a pointer to the object:

```
QObject* someObject = getMethodHelper();
```

Here, I am extremely sure that `someObject` is a type of MethodHelper. I somehow want to cast it to IMethodHelper. How should I go about it?

My current thoughts are like `QObject -> MethodHelper -> IMethodHelper`, like:

```
QObject* someObject = getMethodHelper();
MethodHelper* myHelper = qobject_cast<MethodHelper*>(someObject);
IMethodHelper* myIHelper = dynamic_cast<IMethodHelper*>(myHelper);
```

is there a potential flaw in my approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it the way you present, but it isn't necessary. The Below should work fine.

```
IMethodHelper* myIHelper = dynamic_cast<IMethodHelper*>(someObject);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
IMethodHelper * myIHelper = dynamic_cast<IMethodHelper *>(someObject);
```

Cross casts are legal with `dynamic_cast` - if your types are polymorphic.

5.2.7/8 snippet:

> The run-time check logically executes
>   as follows: — If, in the most derived
>   object pointed (referred) to by v, v
>   points (refers) to a public base class
>   subobject of a T object, and if only
>   one object of type T is derived from
>   the sub-object pointed (referred) to
>   by v, the result is a pointer (an
>   lvalue referring) to that T object.

Comment: But here, IMethodHelper and QObject are not polymorphic

Comment: @hype: `QObject` is. Haven't seen the definition of `IMethodHelper`, but the cross cast will work in this case

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement the answers, there is also [`Q_INTERFACES`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qobject.html#Q_INTERFACES) and [`Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE`](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qtplugin.html#Q_DECLARE_INTERFACE) that allow casting using **qobject_cast** instead of **dynamic_cast**. The documentation advertises them mostly for building plugins, but they can be used in any kind of project.

They are especially useful when creating "services." (As in, does this class implement the service interface `com.example.IFileService/1.0`?) And, of course, they work with RTTI turned off if you ever need to.